# Why is this grid of squares not getting drawn correctly?

Tags: c, opengl, glm-math

Why is this grid of squares not getting drawn correctly?

[image]

I have an array of how the grid gets drawn

```c
// Here, 1 means a wall and 0 means an empty square
const int mapX = 8, mapY = 8, mapSize=mapX*mapY;
int map[] =
{
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
};
```

Then, I fill up an array of vertices and indices

```c
typedef struct
{
    Vertex vertices[4];
} Tile;

for(int y = 0; y < mapY; y++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < mapX; x++)
    {
        int x0 = x * mapSize;
        int y0 = y * mapSize;

        Tile tile = {
            (Vertex){{x0+1, y0+1, 0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}},
            (Vertex){{x0+1, y0 + mapSize-1, 0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}},
            (Vertex){{x0 + mapSize-1, y0 + mapSize-1, 0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}},
            (Vertex){{x0 + mapSize-1, y0+1, 0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}},
        };

        mapVertices[y*mapX + x] = tile;
    }
}

for(size_t i = 0; i < mapSize*6; i += 6)
{
    static int offset = 0;

    mapIndices[i + 0] = 0 + offset;
    mapIndices[i + 1] = 1 + offset;
    mapIndices[i + 2] = 2 + offset;

    mapIndices[i + 3] = 2 + offset;
    mapIndices[i + 4] = 3 + offset;
    mapIndices[i + 5] = 0 + offset;

    offset += 4;
}
```

Finally, drawing it in the main loop

```c
// Changing color for wall
for(int y = 0; y < mapY; y++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < mapX; x++)
    {
        if(map[y*mapX + x] == 1)
        {
            memcpy(mapVertices[y*mapX + x].vertices[0].color, (vec4){1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}, sizeof(vec4));
            memcpy(mapVertices[y*mapX + x].vertices[1].color, (vec4){1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}, sizeof(vec4));
            memcpy(mapVertices[y*mapX + x].vertices[2].color, (vec4){1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}, sizeof(vec4));
            memcpy(mapVertices[y*mapX + x].vertices[3].color, (vec4){1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}, sizeof(vec4));
        }
    }
}

mat4 mapTransform;
glm_mat4_identity(mapTransform);
glm_translate(mapTransform, (vec3){0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f});

mat4 mvp;
glm_mat4_mulN((mat4* []){&projectionMatrix, &viewMatrix, &mapTransform}, 3, mvp);

glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(mapShaderProgram, "mvp"), 1, GL_FALSE, (float*)mvp);

bindVAO(&mapVertexAttributes);
bindVBO(&mapVertexAttributes);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(mapVertices), mapVertices);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(mapIndices)/sizeof(mapIndices[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

0,0 is bottom left on the screen.

The grid isn't getting drawn correctly. The squares aren't in the correct position as specified in the array.
If you look at the image and the array side by side, you will notice it

Why is this happening?
How do I fix this?

Comment: In your array 0,0 is top left. Where is 0,0 on your screen?

Comment: 0,0 is Bottom left

Comment: In your array or on the screen?

Comment: Please clarify what "this" means in "Why is this happening?". I have a suspicion, but pointing it out did not seem to trigger an insight for you. So please describe what the problem is you want to fix. Or to put it differently: You have a nice grid of squares, which as far as I can tell matches what I expect the code to produce. Why do you disagree?

Comment: 0,0 is bottom left on the screen

Comment: No, the grid isn't getting drawn correctly. The squares aren't in the correct position as specified in the array. If you look at the image and the array side by side, you will notice it.

Comment: I don't know why "this" is happening?

Comment: Kind of, Should I iterate over the array in reverse?

Comment: Wow, Thank you! It works. Please post this as the answer.

Comment: Not really sure why this question was closed. I can see that *initially* there was a need to "clarify" what the screen coordinate system is - but the edit adding that "detail" was made **before** the last close vote was cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely at your output you will find that the squares on the screen match the content of your array but with inversed lines.

This is because the coordinates on your screen start with `(0,0)` in bottom left corner, while in your array `(0.0)` is in top left element.

You need to transform y coordinate while iterating over your array:

Simply change the calculation of cell in your condition:

```c
for(int y = 0; y < mapY; y++)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < mapX; x++)
    {
        if(map[y*mapX + x] == 1)
        {
            memcpy(mapVertices[y*mapX + x].vertices[0].color, (vec4){1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}, sizeof(vec4));
            memcpy(mapVertices[y*mapX + x].vertices[1].color, (vec4){1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}, sizeof(vec4));
            memcpy(mapVertices[y*mapX + x].vertices[2].color, (vec4){1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}, sizeof(vec4));
            memcpy(mapVertices[y*mapX + x].vertices[3].color, (vec4){1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}, sizeof(vec4));
        }
    }
}
```

to

```c
        if(map[(mapY-y-1)*mapX + x] == 1)
```